# Rerun http post request if response time is longer than n seconds in Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, time, response

I am calling REST API with Java but there are occasional delays in the response sometimes. So I want to somehow check if the response is taking too long (for example 2 or 3 seconds) and restart/rerun the http post request, because I don't need a request that is "stuck" at waiting for a response which might come a lot, a lot later.

This is my piece of code so far:

```
private final CloseableHttpClient client;
HttpResponse response;
List<NameValuePair> parameters;
HttpPost post;

public String getRoleData(int roleid) {
    this.post = new HttpPost(this.createUrl("role/eventdata"));
    this.post.setHeader("apikey", this.apikey);
    this.parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    this.parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("roleid", String.valueOf(roleid)));
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.parameters));
        this.response = client.execute(post);
        String JsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(this.response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return JsonResponse;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.out.println("API Unsupported instruction entry");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("API IO issue");
    }
    return "Empty response";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int timeoutInMillis = 10;
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().
              setConnectTimeout(timeoutInMillis).
              setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeoutInMillis).
              setSocketTimeout(timeoutInMillis).build();
        final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                  .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://reqres.in/api/api/users");
        //this.post.setHeader("apikey", this.apikey);
        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new NameValuePair("name", "test1"));
        parameters.add(new NameValuePair("job", "job1"));
        try {
            //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.parameters));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(jsonResponse);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            System.out.println("API Unsupported instruction entry");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO issue" + ex.getCause().getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

It should be somewhat similar to above. Check RequestConfig part & Exception handling part. You can add a flag in error handling & retry again. We are setting up timeout values here for http client. You can go through some java doc for more details.

By the way, you are using POST method which is by definition not idempotent. So you need to be careful while rerunning the same request again. The server might have processed already after you got the timeout.

Comment: I tried this example but it's not working at all. [image link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/jf2Yczm3SDaVVg8s0Z-GFQ.png)

Comment: @IndiFFer3nT Can you post the whole code? Also can you be more specific on what is not working? I guess you trying to mean it is not throwing error after 3 sec or so.

Comment: well the code is exactly the way you told me to make it. I just added a while loop so that I can retry the request if the answer takes longer than 3 secs. (like I showed you the picture above). But after these new changes the program doesn't work. It gives Error parsing Role JSON from API Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException which means that the response is not fully received or that the reponse is empty, I am not sure which exactly.

Comment: @IndiFFer3nT can't debug without full code, looks like a separate issue. anyways i have updated the above code with a fully working class that you can use for reference. check the printed Exception class name when timeout happens. you can increase the timeout using "timeoutInMillis" field. then you will get proper json response. hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm can you tell me which part of the code is responsible for retrying the http request if timeout it reached?

Comment: as mentioned in the post, you can have a status flag which will be set if timeout exception is thrown. you can use that flag to loop.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!